# Node.js Websocket Using Windows Credentials

Tags: node.js, ssl, networking, websocket, ws

I am attempting to create a secure websocket connection to a server that uses self-signed SSL certificates. I have added them to my windows machine as trusted certificates, but when I run the node.js app I still get SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN. After a bit of digging, I discovered that node.js does not us Windows certificates by default. How can I make it use windows certificates for websockets? I am using the 'ws' module.

Comment: I think you want this:  https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue, but it may not be applicable to everyone. I solved the issue by adding the line `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"`. This essentially ignores the SSL certificate. I would not recommend this if you care about things like security, but for a quick and dirty POC it works fine.